# migrating data from Sybase sql Anywhere 11 to Sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-migration, sap-ase, sqlanywhere

I want to migrate data from Sybase Sql Anywhere 11 to SQL server 2008 R2. But I am not geeting the soluition that how to import the data. Can you suggest me some queries or free tool to import the data into sql server.
[Sybase sql editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udRM1.png) Also I am providing connection string for the sybase db.
[Connection String for Sybase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udRM1.png)
Please help me out.

Thanks in Advanced..!!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you, I would say, would be Microsoft Visual Studio Express. It's their free version and has the ability to connect to databases. It'll also allow you to code in C#, VB, and mess with LINQ to run queries against your Sybase server and even insert (migrate) data from the sybase into the Sql Server you mentioned